# Login with Facebook on the website on a iphone/ipad device is not working for google app only

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I click on "login with facebook" it then takes me back to the same page. This is currently occuring only on Iphone device and only on the google app.In other app like google chrome, mozilla firefox and safari it's working fine with them but in google app it redirect on the same page.
I am using latest version of sdk v3.2

I have tried changing of sdk version v3.2 to v2.5 but nothing changed.
i think also the problem may be promise rejected in ms.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appId      : FB_APP_KEY,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.2' // Facebook Latest Version.
});
}

handlefbsignin(type){
    var self = this;
    FB.login(function(response) {
       console.log(response) //login with facebook with iphone 
       device's only on google app not get response and redirect on 
       same page 
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
}
```

it should be login.